# Printing a vector of reference_wrapper<int>

Tags: c++, clang

I have the following test code that's runnable under clang.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::vector<int> vs{1, 2, 4, 5};

    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> vs1;

    for (int i : vs) {
        std::cout << "loop: " << i << std::endl;
        vs1.emplace_back(i);
    }

    for (auto p : vs1) {
        std::cout << p << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can plug that into https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_clang (or locally). The result is:

```
loop: 1
loop: 2
loop: 4
loop: 5
5
5
5
5
```

1. I'd expect 1,2,4,5, not 5 all the way.
2. The code won't work on non-clang. Where's the problem?

Comment: Just to be clear: contrary to what your title suggests, it isn’t the *printing* that’s the problem here.

Comment: The way to fix this is to take references to ints in the vector: `for (int& i : vs)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i` is a *local variable* inside its declaring `for` loop. It is a *copy* of each `int` in the `vs` vector. You are thus (via the `emplace_back()` call) creating `reference_wrapper` objects that refer to a local variable, keeping the references alive after the lifetime of the referred-to variable (`i`) has ended. This is **undefined behavior**.

The fix is to make `i` be a *reference* to each `int`, not a *copy*, that way the `reference_wrapper`s refer to the `int`s in `vs` as expected:

```
for (int& i : vs)
```

Answer (score 3):

First, you forgot `<functional>` header.
Second, `reference_wrapper<int>` stores **reference** to an `int`. Not its value. So in this loop:

```
for (int i : vs) {
    std::cout << "loop: " << i << std::endl;
    vs1.emplace_back(i);
}
```

You are changing value of `i` but not its place in memory. It is always the same variable. That's why it prints the last value stored in that variable, which is `5`.

Comment: *Technically*, this is **undefined behavior**, as the loop is saving **dangling references** into `vs1`. There is no guarantee that the compiler will reuse the same memory for `i` on each loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You may imagine this range- based for loop

```
for (int i : vs) {
    std::cout << "loop: " << i << std::endl;
    vs1.emplace_back(i);
}
```

the following way

```
for ( auto first = vs.begin(); first != vs.end(); ++first )
{
    int i = *first;
    vs1.emplace_back(i);
}
```

that is within the loop you are dealing with the local variable i that will not be alive after exiting the loop.

You need to use a reference to elements of the vector like

```
for (int &i : vs) {
    std::cout << "loop: " << i << std::endl;
    vs1.emplace_back(i);
}
```